# How to animate text gradient color to always move in one direction

Tags: html, css, transition

I have a text that is black and on hover the gradient moves from left to right. But after the hover, the gradient moves back to left. I want it to move on the rigth. How could i achieve that?

This is the example code that i currently use

```css
.gradlr {
  color: #0000;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #314199, #54c0c7 50%, #000 0)
    var(--_p, 100%) / 200% no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}
.gradlr:hover {
  --_p: 0%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="gradlr">Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done using transitions, as they can only morph between 2 simple states. To achieve this continuous effect, you would need to use CSS animations.

You can define a keyframe animation which includes at 0% your starting point, 50% your end point, and then at 100% an overshoot to move the gradient further left to reach the starting point again. At that point the animation will restart at 0% and it will look like an infinite animation to the left.

Here's an article to get started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

you can use `to left` as first param to `linear-gradient` :

```css
.gradlr {
  color: #0000;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #314199, #54c0c7 50%, #000 0)
    var(--_p, 100%) / 200% no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}
.gradlr:hover {
  --_p: 0%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="gradlr">Test</h1>
```

Comment: no, i meant when on hover, the gradient moves onto text from left to rigth. when i stop hovering, the gradient color moves back from right to left (dissappears). I just want it to dissappear from left to right.

Answer (score -1):

I updated in the `hover`, please check and tell me if that what you want ?

```css
.gradlr {
  color: #0000;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #314199, #54c0c7 50%, #000 0)
    var(--_p, 100%) / 200% no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}
.gradlr:hover {
  --_p: 85%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="gradlr">Test</h1>
```